# class lvalue only member fuction with shared_ptr

Tags: c++

Using lvalue only member function with shared_ptr

Output

```
test_object::test_object()
example::get_container() &
container::container() 
container::get() &
container::~container()
```

i want the container object's get() function to not get called by rvalue.
So i added & keyword to get().

But when i use this with shared_ptr, this make & keyword of get() obsolete.
So is there another good trick to make this work with shared_ptr??

I have one solution of using static member function, and it works.
But it is dirty.

```
class test_object
{
public:
test_object()
{
    cout << "test_object::test_object()" << endl;
}
~test_object()
{
    cout << "test_object::~test_object()" << endl;
}
};

template<typename type>
class container
{
public:
container(type* data) : pdata(data)
{
    cout << "container::container() " << endl;
}
~container()
{
    cout << "container::~container() " << endl;
}

type* get() &
{
    cout << "container::get() &" << endl;
    return pdata;
}

private:

type* pdata;
};

template<typename type = test_object>
class example
{
public:

shared_ptr<container<type>> get_container() &
{
    cout << "example::get_container() &" << endl;
    return make_shared<container<type>>(&data);
}

private:

type data;
};

int main()
{
example ex;
auto data = ex.get_container()->get();
//this should make compiler error,but 
//it doesn't because get() is called by lvalue container object in rvalue 
//shared_ptr. i want this code to make compiler error 

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way. The referent of a pointer, accessed either via `*` or `->` is always an lvalue. It's baked into the language, and the standard library smart pointer types fall in line with the core language on this.

`shared_ptr<container<type>>::operator->` eventually returns `container<type>*`, to which the arrow operator is applied. The arrow operator is equivalent to doing `(*ptr).get()`. So you will always be applying `get()` to what the language considers an lvalue.

And *it is* an lvalue. Just because the shared pointer is a temporary, doesn't change the fact that it points at occupied storage, at an lvalue.

Comment: Thank you sir. then I must make a static function which gets lvalue of shared_ptr as a parameter.

Comment: @Hunter - I confess I did not quite understand what you are trying to accomplish here. I suspect you may be asking about your design instead of about the problem itself (for which a better design may be possible). You can always [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you want input on that.

Comment: I'm making a kind of buffer synchronization system. The reason i want to use shared_ptr is i want to unlock buffer automatically when i return from a function.

Comment: @Hunter - If you want to ask about way to accomplish that, then please ask another question (i.e. post another SO question). Comments are not the proper way to discuss this. And while you prepare it, make sure you don't accidentally ask an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) by accident. You may be surprised by what this community can come up with if you ask a good question.